# Is there any software to maintain a track of all files in a folder. Like a database?

Tags: files, directory, database

I am aware of a few that use tags and metadata but the actual database where the records are tracked is not accessible. I am interested in a simple spreadsheet that gives me a list of all files added in a folder with certain metadata.